# xampp server not working windows10

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

[image]

I'm using windows10 and my php version is

```
C:\Users\Admin>php -v
PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  1 2017 21:10:46) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

I have installed `xampp` on my system. When I go to browser(Mozilla firefox), and hit url `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

It keeps on loading forever and It never show phpmyadmin OR `http://localhost` apache server homepage.

can anyone help me to resolve it.
Thanks.

Comment: What about error log?

Comment: where can I see error log? It show blank screen on browser.

Comment: @Aamir click on logs (the most right button after `stop`, `admin`...)

Comment: Take a look at the ports apache is using. For me it says "80, 443" which are the default ports for http and https. If you use an other port you need to specify this in your browser url as well: `http://localhost:3630`.

Comment: Thanks @chade_ ... So there are three log files, Apache(access,log), Apache(error.log), PHP(php_error_log) which one are you asking?

Comment: @Aamir Especially `error.log` is important, `php_error_log` may also be helpful.

Comment: @RolandStarke when I restart xampp, Now it's showing ports  3818 for Apache.

Comment: @chade_ The recent logs in error.log is "[Wed Nov 29 12:54:30.413049 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4248:tid 580] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 29 12:54:30.513449 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4248:tid 580] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 29 12:54:30.537001 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4248:tid 580] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
"

Comment: @RolandStarke Not working http://localhost:3818 way.